# Webview in backgroud: is it a bad practice ? Is HttpClient the solution?

Tags: android, webview, androidhttpclient, android-async-http

I have an Activity that runs a `WebView` and inject some JS into a site (which i don't have control) and returns me some data. I need to do the same thing on background, with a service. How can i do this ?

**NOTE**: I'm already using an `IntentService`, `AlarmManager` and `BroadcastReceivers`. I only wanna know the better way to implement this service (WebView, Http-Client, others..)

**Ps**.: I think that if i instantiate a `WebView` 0Wx0 through service would be dirty. Am i wrong ?

**Ps**: I read a little about HttpClient, but I do not know if it is useful to me.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

> webView.loadUrl() is asynchronous

so its already on a background thread: it returns immediately and WebView keeps working on a separate thread.

To get a callback for WebView page loading use `WebViewClient.onPageFinished(....)`

Comment: Sorry, i wasnt clear. I actually use onPageFinished in my UI WebView. But i need to do the same work in the background, with a service.

Answer (score 0):

have your service create a new webview activity. so on some event in the background you can start a webview Activity and do the same thing. Depending on the type of event you can use a intentService otherwise a sticky long running service

Comment: I am using a IntentService to do this. But `WebView`s can only be instantiated from UI Thread. I need to do this with IntentService :/